# Format String to particular format ##.###/##.###

Tags: c#

I have a requirement to format all my string to the format ##.###/##.### Example: If input value is 3/4 then i need to format it to 03.000/04.000 If my input value is 1.4/2.0 then i need to format it to 01.400/02.000 I have tried the below, which is giving the expected output. Can someone suggest is there any direct function or better way to do this.

```
using System; 
class Test { 
// Main Method 
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    
    String input = "23.3/4.0"; 
    String[] splittedValue = input.Split('/'); 
    Decimal numerator=Convert.ToDecimal(splittedValue[0]);
    Decimal denominator=Convert.ToDecimal(splittedValue[1]);
    String format = "00.000";
    String test1  =  numerator.ToString(format);
    String test2 =  denominator.ToString(format);
    
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. What is the scope of your question? The program or the string formatting pattern?

Comment: String formatting pattern

Comment: No, I don't think so there is a shorter / more concise way to convert `1.4` to `01.400`. With `N3` you could add precision like `1.400` but without leading zero. With `PadLeft` you could add leading zero, but now you would have two operations instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of being more concise is to split the string by `'/'` and `'.'`and rebuild the 2 strings with padding.  This eliminates 2 conversions and gives the required format:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    
    var input = "23.3/4.0";
    var splittedValue = input.Split( '/', '.' );
    var num = FormatFracParts( splittedValue[0], splittedValue[1] );
    var den = FormatFracParts( splittedValue[2], splittedValue[3] );
    
}

private static string FormatFracParts(params string[] parts)
{
    if(parts.Length != 2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException( @"'parts' must have exactly 2 elements." );
    }
    return $"{parts[0].PadLeft(2, '0')}.{parts[1].PadRight(3, '0')}";
}
```